# DbContext InvalidOperationException

Tags: blazor

I am getting this error when adding a new user, and I can't figure out why.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

I get the error when I loop all users on the page.
I have searched other questions about the same error, but nothing worked for me.

UserOverview.cs

```
// when adding a user
var added = await UsersService.AddUser(UserModel);

// get all users
Users = await UsersService.GetUsers();
```

UserService.cs

```
private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public UsersService(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddUser(Users user)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users;
    }
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsers, UsersService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetUsers()
{
    return _context.Users;
}
```

You do not execute the command, you [defer the execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution). As a result, actual query execution happens asynchronously somewhen later, after your method has exited.  If a new request comes during that execution, the DBContext can get reused by that new request and be accessed by a new thread while still being used for the execution of retrieving the users.

Change the code like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetUsers()
{
    return await _context.Users.ToArrayAsync();
}
```